# Android ADK and Arduino: mAccessory is null

Tags: android, eclipse, arduino, adk, accessory

ADK Mega is not connecting with my Android device! Ainol Aurora Android 4.0.4 with CyanogenMod 9 (file **com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar** is present)
In logcat I see: **mAccessory is null**
When I connect my Arduino board with Android Tablet in Port Monitor (Arduino IDE) i see:

> Device addressed... Requesting device descriptor. found possible
>   device. swithcing to serial mode device supports protocol 1 or higher

But in Android Tablet DemoKit application I see text: **Please connect a DemoKit board.** but nothing happens when I plug it in.

I try use Google API 12 and 15 version, but this take no effect. Error: **mAccessory is null**

Comment: It sounds like maybe you are connecting the android tablet to the arduino's USB **device** port, as you would connect a PC to the arduino.  If you want to use the accessory mode, you'd need an arduino with a USB host shield, so the arduino is the master and the tablet the device.  It looks like maybe your tablet is successful in being the master, so can you just use that mode?

Comment: I use Seeeduino ADK Main Board

Comment: which connector on the board are you using?

Comment: I use USB connector :))) That's not the point.  
In MicroBridge mode Android and Seeeduino ADK Main Board work fine! But not worked in ADK mode.

Comment: Sorry I thought that was logcat output not arduino debug output.  So you are saying that you can talk ADB with the tablet as a device, but cannot talk the ADK protocol?

Comment: Анатолий: what firmware is loaded on your Arduino Mega ADK?

Comment: @Chris Stratton, yes! Connection between Seeduino and Android Tablet work fine in MicroBridge Mode, but not worked in ADK mode.

Comment: @vt. I uploaded sketch from adk_release_20120606.zip archive (demokit.pde). This sketch compiled in Arduino 1.0 without problem and work fine

Comment: What Android device are you using? Not all devices actually support USB accessory mode, because ADK devices use a little USB magic to communicate with an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Arduino firmware advertise the signature that is [understood](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/adk.html#firmware) by DemoKit?

Comment: I have [Seeeduino ADK Main Board](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/seeeduino-adk-main-board-p-846.html)
It's board full compatibility with ADK and MicroBridge modes.
Board work in MicroBridge mode with my Android Tablet, but not work in ADK mode. I need ADK.

Comment: vt. is asking about the firmware (arduino sketch) you have loaded on your board, which is a very separate question from what board you have.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I uploaded sketch from adk_release_20120606.zip archive (arduino_libs/AndroidAccessory/examples/demokit/demokit.pde). This sketch compiled in Arduino 1.0 without problem and work fine.  
After run I see this text in Port Monitor: 
> Device addressed... Requesting device descriptor. found possible device. swithcing to serial mode device supports protocol 1 or higher

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Galaxy Tab. I updated touchwiz but still I got possible device found and then disconnected state and looping in it.
Anyway, I modified code for AndroidAccessory.cpp slightly where it switches to serial

```
switchDevice(1);
```

to

```
connected = switchDevice(1);
```

and then it worked fine.